# equivalent of "didAddAnnotationViews" for removing pins?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a mapview. I've implemented didAddAnnotationViews to show a custom fade in animation for my pins.

This is called successfully when pins are added to the map, but not when pins are removed. I can't find an equivalent function in the documentation. Is there another way to implement a custom fade out animation for specific pins?

Comment: I would like to know this as well!

Answer (score 5):

I've created the category to MKMapView with the following methods

```
- (void)removeAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation animated:(BOOL)shouldAnimate;
- (void)removeAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations animated:(BOOL)shouldAnimate;
```

that you can call instead of calling

```
- (void)removeAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation;
- (void)removeAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations;
```

Here's the implementation:

```
- (void)removeAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation animated:(BOOL)shouldAnimate {
    if (!shouldAnimate)
        [self removeAnnotation:annotation];
    else {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [self viewForAnnotation:annotation];
        CGRect endFrame = annotationView.frame;
    endFrame = CGRectMake(
                       annotationView.frame.origin.x, 
                       annotationView.frame.origin.y - self.bounds.size.height, 
                       annotationView.frame.size.width, 
                       annotationView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                          delay:0.0f 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         annotationView.frame = endFrame;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self removeAnnotation:annotation];
                     }];
    }
}

- (void)removeAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations animated:(BOOL)shouldAnimate {
    if (!shouldAnimate)
        [self removeAnnotations:annotations];
    else {
        NSTimeInterval delay = 0.0;
        for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations) {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [self viewForAnnotation:annotation];
            CGRect endFrame = annotationView.frame;
            endFrame = CGRectMake(
                              annotationView.frame.origin.x, 
                              annotationView.frame.origin.y - self.bounds.size.height, 
                              annotationView.frame.size.width, 
                              annotationView.frame.size.height);
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                                  delay:delay
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                             animations:^{
                                 annotationView.frame = endFrame;
                             } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 [self removeAnnotation:annotation];
                             }];
            delay += 0.05;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no delegate methods for removing annotations, but you can achieve animated effect the following way:

When you want to remove annotation, first fade its view out with animation and remove annotation when animation completes. You code may look like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void){
                            annotationView.alpha = 0.0f;
                        }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
                 }];
```

Comment: How do you get an annotationView?

Comment: @Dima with viewForAnnotation: method in MKMapView